# invoke-sqlcmd is not recognised as the name of a comdlet

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a few problems here.

Im trying to run the following sql to extract the contents to a txt file

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "exec [web_directory].[dbo].selectextractforjs" -ServerInstance "IISServer" -Database "web_directory" > c:\download\outputFileName.js
```

but everytime I run it from a new powershell window I have to run these two cmds first

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

Which is ok I suppose but I want to run it as a schedule task every night, so I have the following batch file

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
PAUSE
```

and the following .ps1 file

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "exec [web_directory].[dbo].selectextractforjs" -ServerInstance "IISServer -Database "web_directory" > c:\download\outputFileName.js
```

but everytime I run this I get the error 'the term .....ps1' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet etc etc

it's running on a windows 2008 server

can anyone help

thanks

Comment: Sorry everyone just forget this, I've just noticed the powershell is only extracting certain amounts of data. So I'll have to think of a different way

Comment: Please delete the question if it no longer needs to be answered.